# What is the best way to detect a button push - Arduino

Tags: while-loop, arduino, do-while

I have a function which is basically a Whack-A-Mole game using LEDs and Push Buttons. LED-A lights up, and the user has to push BTN-A to turn it off... and we move on to the next LED/BTN combo.

My circuitry works and i can turn each LED on/off individually and detect each button push as well. However, once in my game loop (see below), I see some odd behavior.

My code looks like this:

```
void gameTwo(){
  Serial.println("We are in Game 2");
  playGameTwo();
  //lightShowTwo();

  // Set game state
  int gameState = 0;

  // Start counter
  elapsedMillis timeElapsed;

  // First LED
  digitalWrite(ledB, HIGH);
  while(digitalRead(btnB) != HIGH){
    //Serial.print("btnBstate is:  ");
    //Serial.println(digitalRead(btnB));
    if(digitalRead(btnB) == 1){
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(ledB, LOW);
      Serial.print(timeElapsed);
    }
  }

  // Second LED
  digitalWrite(ledE, HIGH);
  while(digitalRead(btnE) != HIGH){
    //Serial.print("btnBstate is:  ");
    //Serial.println(digitalRead(btnE));
    if(digitalRead(btnE) == 1){
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(ledE, LOW);
      Serial.print(timeElapsed);
    }
  }

  // Third LED
  digitalWrite(ledF, HIGH);
  while(digitalRead(btnF) != HIGH){
    //Serial.print("btnBstate is:  ");
    //Serial.println(digitalRead(btnE));
    if(digitalRead(btnF) == 1){
      delay(50); // these dalays DO NOT work
      digitalWrite(ledF, LOW);
      Serial.print(timeElapsed);
    }
  }  

  // End Game - Publish Elapsed Time
    gameState = 1;

  // record user's elapsed time
  int userTime = timeElapsed;
  Serial.print("Game Finished - Your time was:  ");
  Serial.print(timeElapsed);
  Serial.println(" ms!");



}
```

The problem is that it doesn't always work. Sometimes LED-A turn off, sometimes it stays on.

As you can see, I've tried adding a small delay(50) also to no avail.

What is the best way to detect button presses in a while loop.

Bonus question: I'm hard coding the game (eg LEDA, LEDB... LEDx). There should be a better way, perhaps using an array, to push the game sequence. As I'm not a programmer, I'd appreciate some guidance or an article to read to get more educated on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while` to loop until a button is pressed.

Using arrays will make it much easier, here I use an array for leds and a another for buttons. The numbers in arrays represents the pins. I inserted `random()` function that will make it more challenging. Each loop it takes a random ledPin for `led[]` and a corresponding btnPin for `btn[]`.

```
//suppose that the button in pin 4 is for led in pin 1
//the button in pin 5 is for led in pin 2
//and the button in pin 6 is for led in pin 3

int led[] = {1, 2, 3};
int btn[] = {4, 5, 6};
int count = 3;
int ledPin = 0;
int btnPin = 0;
int previous = 0;

void setup() {
 for( ledPin=0; ledPin<count; ledPin++ ){
  pinMode(led[ledPin], OUTPUT);
 }
}

void loop() {
  ledPin = random(1, 4);              //pick a random number 1-3
  while( ledPin == previous ){        //if it is the same as previous, change it
    ledPin = random(3); }
  btnPin = ledPin + 3;                //btnPin set to 4-6
  digitalWrite(led[ledPin], HIGH);
  while( digitalRead(btn[btnPin]) == LOW ){}    //or HIGH according to pulling method
  digitalWrite(led[ledPin],LOW);
  previous = ledPin;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response. The problem with your code is that it does NOT wait for the corresponding button to be pressed. It simply moves on executing the code with btnPress = low - which is not the desired result. The crux of my issue is that I haven't been able to figure out how to wait for the btnPress to go high. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `while` to loop until the pushbutton is pressed:              

`while( digitalRead(button)==LOW ){ //do nothing }`

Comment: @fr Checking the state of the switch will depend on how you connected it. Resistor pull up or resistor pull down illustration here: (https://www.elprocus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11-8-2014-9-44-39-AM.jpg) . Also you can see more arduino 
questions here: (https://arduino.stackexchange.com) and here: (http://www.arduino.cc).

Comment: @frednikgohar I've updated the comment. I haven't tested the code but I think it should work fine. For a larger whack-a-mole game try this: (https://github.com/rishigoel/whackAMole1)

Comment: I also came to that conclusion: the trick is to use the while loop to detect the button press. This essentially stops the rest of the code from executing until the button press event happens. Thanks for following up.